# How to Disable type justInTimeInstall continue button if i didn't create chat history

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

How to Disable type justInTimeInstall continue button if i didn't create chat history[image: justInTimeInstall with continue button]

Comment: Can you please share the repro steps and explain this issue little more?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: i done some modification in bot level now. so instead of disable the button hide/show modification added for justInTimeInstall, so it's working thanks.@HunaidHanfee-MSFT